# Use ajax to filtering data table in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

i'm using codeigniter to build my project. I want to make filter use select box with ajax, but i confused. when user choose values from select box, then i want the table just show data that contain select box values. Can anyone help me please...

Comment: It's a far too broad question for SO. Why don't you show us what you tried for example ?

Comment: cause i confused sir

Comment: i just looking for reference about thar case

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function show_result()
{
    if($('#selectbox').val()!='')
    {
            $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:'<?php echo base_url()?>controller/controller_function',
        data:'selectvalue='+$('#selectbox').val(),
        cache: false,
        beforeSend : function ()
        {
                    $("#idAjaxLoader").css("display",'');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#idAjaxLoader").css("display",'none');
            $('#table-div').html(data);
                    },

        error: function(data){

        //return false;
        }

        }); 

    }


}
</script>
```

write query in controller's **controller_function** and then load view with table by your expected result

Comment: the query in controller just load data from table ?

Comment: in view write your filtered table again and replace original with this one
by using  $('#table-div').html(data);